# Understanding Neighborhood Majority Statistic in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics

[image]

Here both 12 and 13 are equal so would the neighborhood majority be null for this 3 by 3 neighborhood?

Comment: What tool are you using?  Have you reviewed it's documentation?  Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

[image]

Focal statistics output:

[image]

Conclusion:
If no solution found cell values replaced by NO DATA value.

Comment: thanks this is correct and was really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/smoothing-zone-edges-with-boundary-clean-and-majority-filter.htm#GUID-CBD68932-69B7-469B-9DCB-8A743B72B908), no replacement will be done in your example:

> The Majority Filter tool replaces cells based on the majority value in
>   their contiguous neighborhoods. The tool has two criteria to satisfy
>   before a replacement can occur. First, the number of neighboring cells
>   with the same value must be large enough to be the majority value, or
>   at least half the cells must have the same value (depending on the
>   parameter specified). That is, three out of four or five out of eight
>   connected cells must have the same value with the majority parameter
>   and two out of four or four out of eight are needed for the half
>   parameter. Second, those cells must be contiguous to the center of the
>   specified filter (for example, three out of four cells must be the
>   same). The second criteria concerning the spatial connectivity of the
>   cells minimizes the corruption of cellular spatial patterns. If these
>   criteria are not met, no replacement occurs, and the cell retains its
>   value.

Comment: so for focal statistics the majority would then return null but the max would be 20 and range 17 etc